# How to pass parameters into a method in Apache Camel using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

```java
rest()
    .get("/{id}")
    .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .route()
    .setBody(() - > orderService.viewOrder())
    .endRest();
```

I am using apache 2.24.0 version.
how to pass id parameter to viewOrder method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters are mapped to message headers with the same name, so in this case you can get the value of the id like:

```
rest()
  .get("/{id}")
  .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  .route()
  .process(e -> {
     String id = e.getIn().getHeader("id", String.class);
     ...
  });
```